# Defining different window.open target URLs in body

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm using a `JavaScript` library `lightbox` without jQuery in an external js file, and I want to configure a button there to link to several different URLs (Clicking on button 1 would open link 1, clicking on button 2 would open link 2).

I got the button to open a new window using `window.open('link1.html', '_blank')`. 
However I couldn't figure out how to to define several different target URLs, preferably in the body of my code.

Is it possible to configure it in a way, that the `window.open` function would fetch different target URLs back in the body?

It is this lightbox: https://jiri.hybek.cz/wa-mediabox/
which runs completely on an external js file, and only the images are defined in the body as follows:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-mediabox="my-gallery-name" data-title="Sample image">
<img src="image-thumb.jpg" alt="Image" />
```

I want to change the open button function in the js file to open an url, which is but defined in the body (like the images).
All I need is the right command that would lead the `window.open` function to fetch their different target URLs in the body, somewhere where also the images are defined.

The button function is defined as follows (I replaced the target with ??? as this is basically what I'm asking about):

```
this.openBtn.addEventListener("click",function(t){t.stopPropagation(),i.open('') win = window.open(???,'_blank');win.focus();})
```

The body holds an image shuffler, with the images opening in the lightbox. The button opens in the lighbox, and should refer from there to the target URLs.

```
<div class="grid"><div class="grid-item"><a href="img/image1.jpg" data-mediabox="my-gallery-name" data-title="text" ???="link1.html"><img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Image"/></a></div><div class="grid-item"><a href="img/image2.png" data-mediabox="my-gallery-name" data-title="text" ???="link2.html"><img src="img/image2.png" /></a>
```

My question is:
How to make the `window.open` function fetch the different target URLs from the body?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Probably. But a lot more detail is needed. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with some example of what you are trying to do

Comment: Take the time to post sample.

Comment: Honestly, you should probably just use an a tag: `<a href="linkA.html" target="_blank">link</a>` and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ahh, I finally see what you're trying to do. The answer is: yes, that is definitely possible; however, doing it that way is not quite as simple as you probably hoped and will require several changes to the library itself. It looks like you were trying to edit the minified source (`wa-mediabox.min.js`), which would make things even more difficult.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I tried. I got as far as having the open button open a new tab, but can't quite figure out which command would fetch the url from the body and how to mark (and where to place) the target url in the body... (for some reason I thought that would be easy...)
I would really like to go with this option, so however difficult it is, I would be very grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions for you, one is kind of hacky, but it's a single line change, the other is more elegant, but requires a few more modifications. Note that I am making the changes to the original JavaScript source file (non-minified).

For both of these solutions, the HTML will be the same; you add a `data-custom-url` attribute to the `<a>` tag and set the value to whatever page you want to open for that image:

```html
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/" data-custom-url="http://google.com/search?q=custom+link" data-mediabox="my-gallery-name" data-title="Sample image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Image" />
</a>
```

## Single line version

Change the `window.open` line in the `WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.openSource` function to this:

```js
window.open( document.querySelector(`a[href='${this.mediaList[this.current].src}']`).getAttribute("data-custom-url") || this.mediaList[this.current].src );
```

This will grab the value of the `data-custom-url` attribute from the HTML and open it, falling back to the default value if it doesn't exist. The "hacky" part of this is that it requires looking up the original `<a>` tag to get the attribute value. It could also have problems if you have multiple links that point to the same image.

## Full version

This version adds the custom url to the media objects that are created internally in the script so that it doesn't have to search the DOM for them at the time the link is clicked. You can view all the changes to the file [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/mD7u6B37).

```
/*
 * WA MediaBox
 *
 * @author WA Studio <www.webarts.name>
 * @author Jiri Hybek <jiri@hybek.cz>
 * @license MIT
 */

(function(){

    /*
     * Preloader constructor
     */
    var Preloader = function(){

        this.el = document.createElement("div");
        this.el.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader");

        this.wrap = document.createElement("div");
        this.wrap.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-wrap");

        this.spinner = document.createElement("div");
        this.spinner.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-spinner");

        this.patch = document.createElement("div");
        this.patch.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-patch");

        this.clipperLeft = document.createElement("div");
        this.clipperLeft.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-clipper");
        this.clipperLeft.classList.add("left");

        this.clipperRight = document.createElement("div");
        this.clipperRight.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-clipper");
        this.clipperRight.classList.add("right");

        var circle = document.createElement("div");
        circle.classList.add("wa-mediabox-preloader-circle");

        this.patch.appendChild(circle);
        this.clipperLeft.appendChild(circle.cloneNode(true));
        this.clipperRight.appendChild(circle.cloneNode(true));

        this.spinner.appendChild(this.clipperLeft);
        this.spinner.appendChild(this.patch);
        this.spinner.appendChild(this.clipperRight);

        this.wrap.appendChild(this.spinner);
        this.el.appendChild(this.wrap);

    };

    Preloader.prototype.show = function(){

        this.el.classList.remove("hidden");
        this.el.style.display = '';

    };

    Preloader.prototype.hide = function(){

        var self = this;

        this.el.classList.add("hidden");

        setTimeout(function(){

            if(self.el.classList.contains("hidden"))
                self.el.style.display = 'none';

        }, 350);

    };

    /* 
     * Gallery constructor
     */
    var WAMediaBox_Gallery = function(parent){

        this.parent = parent;
        this.mediaList = [];

        this.opened = false;

        this.loaded = false;
        this.current = null;

        this.containerWidth = null;
        this.containerHeight = null;

    };

    /*
     * Media adders
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.addImage = function(src, title, customUrl){

        this.mediaList.push({
            type: "image",
            src: src,
            title: title,
            customUrl: customUrl
        });

        return this.mediaList.length - 1;

    };

    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.addIframe = function(src, title, customUrl, width, height){

        this.mediaList.push({
            type: "iframe",
            src: src,
            title: title,
            customUrl: customUrl,
            width: width,
            height: height
        });

        return this.mediaList.length - 1;

    };

    /*
     * Open gallery
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.open = function(index){

        if(this.opened) return;

        var self = this;

        this.current = -1;
        this.loaded = false;

        //Create overlay and content wrapper
        this.overlay = document.createElement("div");
        this.overlay.classList.add("wa-mediabox-overlay");

        this.frame = document.createElement("div");
        this.frame.classList.add("wa-mediabox-frame");

        this.container = document.createElement("div");
        this.container.classList.add("wa-mediabox-container");

        this.title = document.createElement("div");
        this.title.classList.add("wa-mediabox-title");

        this.loading = new Preloader();

        //Buttons
        this.closeBtn = document.createElement("button");
        this.closeBtn.classList.add("wa-mediabox-close");
        this.closeBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" /></svg>';
        this.closeBtn.setAttribute("title", this.parent.lang.close);

        this.prevBtn = document.createElement("button");
        this.prevBtn.classList.add("wa-mediabox-prev");
        this.prevBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.41,16.58L10.83,12L15.41,7.41L14,6L8,12L14,18L15.41,16.58Z" /></svg>';
        this.prevBtn.setAttribute("title", this.parent.lang.prev);

        this.nextBtn = document.createElement("button");
        this.nextBtn.classList.add("wa-mediabox-next");
        this.nextBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M8.59,16.58L13.17,12L8.59,7.41L10,6L16,12L10,18L8.59,16.58Z" /></svg>';
        this.nextBtn.setAttribute("title", this.parent.lang.next);

        this.openBtn = document.createElement("button");
        this.openBtn.classList.add("wa-mediabox-open");
        this.openBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M14,3V5H17.59L7.76,14.83L9.17,16.24L19,6.41V10H21V3M19,19H5V5H12V3H5C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V12H19V19Z" /></svg>';
        this.openBtn.setAttribute("title", this.parent.lang.openInNew);

        //Put together
        this.frame.appendChild(this.container);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.title);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.loading.el);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.closeBtn);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.prevBtn);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.nextBtn);
        this.frame.appendChild(this.openBtn);

        this.overlay.appendChild(this.frame);
        document.body.appendChild(this.overlay);

        //Bind events
        this.overlay.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.close();

        });

        this.closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.close();

        });

        this.prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.prev();

        });

        this.nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.next();

        });

        this.container.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.next();

        });

        this.openBtn.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            self.openSource();

        });

        //Resize
        this.resizeHandler = function(){

            self.resizeContainer();

        };

        this.keyDownHandler = function(ev){

            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();

            if(ev.keyCode === 37)
                self.prev();
            else if(ev.keyCode === 39)
                self.next();
            else if(ev.keyCode === 27)
                self.close();

            return false;

        };

        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler);
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler);

        //Open
        setTimeout(function(){

            self.overlay.classList.add("opened");

            self.loadMedia(index);

        }, 10);

        //Set opened
        this.opened = true;

    };

    /*
     * Close gallery
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.close = function(){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        var self = this;

        this.overlay.classList.remove("opened");

        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler);
        document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler);

        setTimeout(function(){

            self.overlay.parentElement.removeChild(self.overlay);
            self.opened = false;

            self.nextBtn = null;
            self.prevBtn = null;
            self.closeBtn = null;
            self.openBtn = null;
            self.loading = null;
            self.container = null;
            self.frame = null;
            self.overlay = null;

            self.current = null;
            self.containerWidth = null;
            self.containerHeight = null;

        }, 450);

    };

    /*
     * Resize container
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.resizeContainer = function(){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        //Defaults
        if(!this.containerWidth)
            this.containerWidth = Math.round(this.overlay.offsetWidth * 0.7);

        if(!this.containerHeight)
            this.containerHeight = Math.round(this.overlay.offsetWidth * 0.7);

        var widthLimit = 160;

        if(this.overlay.offsetWidth < 480)
            widthLimit = 70;

        var maxWidth = Math.min(this.overlay.offsetWidth * 0.9, this.overlay.offsetWidth - widthLimit);
        var maxHeight = Math.min(this.overlay.offsetHeight * 0.9, this.overlay.offsetHeight - 64);

        var targetWidth = this.containerWidth;
        var targetHeight = this.containerHeight;

        //Resize if neccesary
        var ratio = targetWidth / targetHeight;

        if(targetWidth > maxWidth){
            targetWidth = Math.round(maxWidth);
            targetHeight = targetWidth / ratio;
        }

        if(targetHeight > maxHeight){
            targetHeight = Math.round(maxHeight);
            targetWidth = targetHeight * ratio;
        }

        //Set styles
        this.frame.style.width = targetWidth + "px";
        this.frame.style.height = targetHeight + "px";

        this.frame.style.marginLeft = -Math.round(targetWidth / 2) + "px";
        this.frame.style.marginTop = -Math.round(targetHeight / 2) + "px";

    };

    /*
     * Set media into container
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.setMedia = function(type, src, title, width, height){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        var self = this;
        this.loaded = false;

        this.frame.classList.remove("can-open-in-new");
        self.frame.classList.remove("has-title");

        //Reset content
        this.container.innerHTML = '';

        //Create proper element
        var mediaEl = null;

        if(type == "image"){

            //Resize
            if(width) this.containerWidth = width;
            if(height) this.containerHeight = height;
            this.resizeContainer();

            mediaEl = document.createElement("img");

            mediaEl.addEventListener("load", function(){

                self.containerWidth = mediaEl.width;
                self.containerHeight = mediaEl.height;

                self.resizeContainer();
                self.frame.classList.add("can-open-in-new");

                //Add to DOM
                self.container.appendChild(mediaEl);

            });

            mediaEl.src = src;

        } else {

            //Resize
            if(width) this.containerWidth = width;
            if(height) this.containerHeight = height + ( title ? 52 : 0 );
            this.resizeContainer();

            mediaEl = document.createElement("iframe");
            mediaEl.src = src;
            mediaEl.setAttribute("width", parseInt(this.frame.style.width));
            mediaEl.setAttribute("height", parseInt(this.frame.style.height) - ( title ? 52 : 0 ));
            mediaEl.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
            mediaEl.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "allowfullscreen");

            //Add to DOM
            this.container.appendChild(mediaEl);

        }

        //Wait for load
        mediaEl.addEventListener("load", function(){

            setTimeout(function(){

                //Set title
                if(title){
                    self.title.innerHTML = title;
                    self.frame.classList.add("has-title");
                }

                //Show
                self.frame.classList.add("loaded");
                self.loading.hide();
                self.loaded = true;

            }, 550);

        });

    };

    /*
     * Load media at index
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.loadMedia = function(index){

        if(!this.opened) return;
        if(index == this.current) return;

        var self = this;

        if(!this.mediaList[index]) throw new Error("Undefined media");

        var load = function(){

            self.setMedia( self.mediaList[index].type, self.mediaList[index].src, self.mediaList[index].title, self.mediaList[index].width, self.mediaList[index].height );

        };

        if(this.loaded){

            this.frame.classList.remove("loaded");
            this.loading.show();
            setTimeout(load, 350);

        } else {

            load();

        }

        if(index > 0)
            this.frame.classList.add("has-prev");
        else
            this.frame.classList.remove("has-prev");

        if(index < this.mediaList.length - 1)
            this.frame.classList.add("has-next");
        else
            this.frame.classList.remove("has-next");

        this.current = index;

    };

    /*
     * Switch to previous media
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.prev = function(){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        var index = Math.max(0, this.current - 1);
        this.loadMedia(index);

    };

    /*
     * Switch to next media
     */
    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.next = function(){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        var index = Math.min(this.mediaList.length - 1, this.current + 1);
        this.loadMedia(index);

    };

    WAMediaBox_Gallery.prototype.openSource = function(){

        if(!this.opened) return;

        window.open( this.mediaList[this.current].customUrl || this.mediaList[this.current].src );

    };

    /*
     * ImageBox constructor
     */
    var WAMediaBox = function(){

        this.lang = {
            prev: "Previous",
            next: "Next",
            close: "Close",
            openInNew: "Open in new window"
        };

        this.galleries = {};

    };

    WAMediaBox.prototype.openGallery = function(gallery, index){

        if(!this.galleries[gallery]) throw new Error("Gallery not found");

        this.galleries[gallery].open(index);

    };

    /*
     * Media adders
     */
    WAMediaBox.prototype.addImage = function(gallery, src, title, customUrl){

        if(!this.galleries[gallery])
            this.galleries[gallery] = new WAMediaBox_Gallery(this);

        return this.galleries[gallery].addImage(src, title, customUrl);

    };

    WAMediaBox.prototype.addIframe = function(gallery, src, title, customUrl, width, height){

        if(!this.galleries[gallery])
            this.galleries[gallery] = new WAMediaBox_Gallery(this);

        return this.galleries[gallery].addIframe(src, title, customUrl, width, height);

    };

    /*
     * Bind single elements
     */
    WAMediaBox.prototype.bind = function(el){

        if(el._waMediaBoxBound) return;

        el._waMediaBoxBound = true;

        var self = this;

        var gallery = el.getAttribute("data-mediabox") || "_";
        var src = String(el.getAttribute("href") || el.getAttribute("data-src"));
        var title = el.getAttribute("data-title");
        var isIframe = ( el.hasAttribute("data-iframe") || src.indexOf("youtube") >= 0 ? true : false );
        var width = ( el.hasAttribute("data-width") ? parseInt(el.getAttribute("data-width")) : null );
        var height = ( el.hasAttribute("data-height") ? parseInt(el.getAttribute("data-height")) : null );
        var customUrl = el.getAttribute("data-custom-url");

        var index = null;

        //Add to gallery
        if(isIframe)
            index = this.addIframe(gallery, src, title, customUrl, width, height);
        else
            index = this.addImage(gallery, src, title, customUrl);

        //Bind open event
        el.addEventListener("click", function(ev){

            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();

            self.openGallery(gallery, index);

            return false;

        });

    };

    /*
     * Bind all elements in given parent node
     */
    WAMediaBox.prototype.bindAll = function(parentEl){

        var elements = parentEl.querySelectorAll("a[data-mediabox]");

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            this.bind(elements.item(i));

    };

    //Assign to window
    window.WAMediaBox = new WAMediaBox();

    //Bind lightbox elements
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){

        window.WAMediaBox.bindAll(document.body);

    });

})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately the full version leaves the open button on my side without any response and the single line version returns a syntax error. 
Also, I've been swapping your JavaScript source file (non-minified) with the original in the file in https://github.com/jirihybek/wa-mediabox and made the changes in the index file, but that wouldn't change any behavior there as well.
Any ideas?
(Thanks again, I'm very grateful for your help...)

Comment: @LiLi What's the syntax error? And what browser are you using?

Comment: I tried it both in Firefox and Safari and the Syntax error is not specified (by dreamweaver).
In what browser did it work?

Comment: If there's an error it should show up in the web console of Firefox (I'm not familiar with Safari). It works for me in both Firefox 58 and Chrome 63.

Comment: It does!! Both in Firefox and Safari! Thank you! I could make it work in my file as well. Yay!!!
Thank you so much!! You're genius (and commited)!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!